# Nil Coalescing Operator Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've got one problem in swift. In Objective-C I write like this:

```
return !item ? self.people.count : item.children.count
```

So, if item is nil it returns self.people.count, otherwise it returns item.children.count. How to write such thing in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (item as? Person)?.children.count ?? self.people.count
```

Comment: Works! I'm just beginning in Swift. Before I used Objective C

Comment: When I run application I get: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on that line. Item is really nil

Answer (score 5):

Don't confuse nil coalescing operator with conditional shorthand operator, which is available both in Swift and Objective-C:

```
return !item ? self.people.count : item.children.count
```

The line above returns `self.people.count` if `!item` evaluates to `true` and `item.children.count` otherwise. It is valid both in Objective-C and Swift. However, if you want to check `item` for not being `nil` value, then in Swift you need to make such a check specifically:

```
return item == nil ? self.people.count : item.children.count
```

Nil coalescing operator allows to rewrite this shorter:

```
return item?.children.count ?? self.people.count
```

If the item is not `nil`, it'd return it's count. Otherwise, you'd get `people`'s count.

For more information, you may want to check out this Swift language guide [chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html).